# Error while installing Packages

Tags: r

I am getting below mentioned error

```
Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/XXXXXDocuments/R/win-library/3.3/filexxxxxxxxxxx/BH/include/boost/geometry/util/readme.txt': Permission denied
```

while installing packages with `install.packages("tidyverse")` and `install.packages("sqldf")` but `install.packages("stringr")` is installing successfully.

My account has Read-Execute rights for the R-library folder.

I can successfully install these packages on a colleague's PC with the same rights and R version.

Comment: Few things I can think off. Try updating R-Studio, then install from **Packages > Install**

Comment: show us the output of `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()` here (you can anonymize your user name in the lib paths if you want)

Comment: please add the exact `install.packages` command that causes the error to your question

Comment: @RYoda exact install packages has been added

Comment: @aman: Don't forget sessionInfo and .libPaths please